# Loop over columns of dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, multiple-columns

How can I loop to perform the same test over columns with similar names in R?

for example I have three columns, named col30, col126, col145. I was thinking something like:

```
x <- c(30, 126, 145)

for (i in x) {

  wilcox.test(col(i) ~ level)

}
```

is not working and provide the following error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : attempt to apply non-function

Comment: the thing is that I have to loop over the column names, for which the first part is the same for all the columns (col), and second part is changing (30, 126, 145)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    summarise_at(vars(col30, col126, col145), wilcox.test, y = level)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` function instead of a `for loop` and iterate the same test for the selected columns:

`apply(df[, c(col30, col126, col145)], 2, wilcox.test ~ level)`

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c(30, 126, 145)
for (i in x) {
    wilcox.test(df[,i] ~ level)
}
```

where df is your data frame.